# add link to image background

Tags: css, hyperlink

I use a custom background image for each page in my wordpress website, with custom css like this :

```
body.page-id-74697 {
background: url("/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/skin-d.jpg")no-repeat fixed top center;
}
```

I want to add a link to this background image! how I can do that?

I tried something like this :

```
<a href="http://????" title="Title of Link" class="page-id-74697">Basic Text For this Link</a>
```

But this doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a href="http://????" title="Title of Link" ><span class="page-id-74697"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Selector { background-image: url("paper.gif"); }
```

And I advice you to add your paths relatively. What you have declared is the absolute path. **Relative path** is declaring the path relative to where the current css file is being saved. Where **absolute path** is declaring the path from the very root of the project.

But in your case i don't really know what's happening, but first make sure the image you linked is in relative path to the current style sheet, and then try deleting ***fixed*** from your css code which will ultimately look like the following,

```
body.page-id-74697 {
    background: url("relative/path/to/the/image.jpg")no-repeat top center;
}
```

Comment: sorry i dont get that? how i can use it ?